# How do I test an HTML Email Template on CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

To confirm a purchase I must send an e-mail to the customer with her shopping cart details. I'd like to test the HTML template to use the appropiate CSS, and of course to check the data that arrives to it. 
What code should I use instead of setting the Email parameters, to watch how the template will render on the Email?

I'm all new on CakePHP, so your help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

~José

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is CakePHP 1.3, but I have a feeling it may work well with 2.0 as well. While there may be other ways to do it, I do by creating a test action in any controller, then return a render call of the email template. Check this out:

```
function email_test()
{
    $this->layout = 'email/html/default';
    $user = $this->User->findById(1);
    $this->set('name', $user['User']['firstname']);
    $this->set('email_heading', 'Welcome to My App');
    return $this->render('/elements/email/html/welcome');
}
```

This action will now render out your email in the browser.

Comment: Long story short, set the layout to your email layout. Set your view variables and then force render the email view you want to see.

Comment: In 2.4 the paths are a little different. Layouts are now under emails/html/default ets

Answer (score 1):

Use the debug transport for testing.

If you want to make it more comfortable write your own transport that creates a new html file in for example APP/tmp/email/.html See the debug transport class as a reference, it's dead easy to do this http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/debug-transport#l-34

See also the book -> http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#using-transports

Comment: So this should work if I'm using the EmailComponent class also?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $this->Email->to = $user_id_array[0]['User']['email'];
    $this->Email->subject = $arrTemplate[0]['EmailTemplate']['subject'];
    $this->Email->replyTo = 'Admin<admin@indianic.com>';
    $this->Email->from = 'Admin<admin@indianic.com>';
    $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
    $this->Email->template = '/elements/email/html/warning_message';

   $this->set('email_message',$arrTemplate[0]['EmailTemplate']['body']);
   $this->Email->send();
```

in this way you can set  template for email

Comment: My problem isn't setting up the template for the e-mail, is checking out how the template will render, before is actually sent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple method I use to show html/plain text content of email in browser that I want to send using cakephp email class i.e. `App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');`.
Just do an `exit` at the end of email template file or (email layout file) and then try to send email. it will render the email content.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print your **email template** on localhost for testing then you can use this code.

```
$this->Email->send();
print_r($this->Email->htmlMessage);
```